# how can i insert id value to a table from another table with laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

i have the controller where i want to insert the id from table to another.

```
public function storecontact(Request $request)
{
    $img_name=time() .'.' . $request->url->getClientOriginalExtension();
    
    $this->validate($request,[
            'content' => 'unique:emails,content,subject'
            
        ]);
    $request->user()->id;
    $email= new Email;
    $email->name=request('name');
    $email->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $email->email=request('email');
    $email->subject=request('subject');
    $email->hood=request('hood');
    $email->street=request('street');
    $email->content=request('content');
    $email->priority=request('priority');
    $email->url=$img_name;
    $email->status=("ממתין לטיפול");
    //$email->subject_id= request($id);
   // $email->subject_id=request($id);
    $email->save();
    $request->url->move(public_path('photos'),$img_name);
    eturn redirect()->back();
   }
```

the relationship for the model Email

```
public function subject()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class);
}
```

the relationship for the model Subject

```
public function emails()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Email::class);
}
```

i think the issue should be in controller it worked for me before maybe some lines of code deleted and i forgot how i did it.

Comment: You mean this? $email->subject_id= $request->user()->id;

Comment: no it inserts the logged in user id, i need the subject id i from another table

Comment: If you have access to the email
You can get the subject id attached to it by $email->subject()->id;

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

**You can just follow simple steps:**

```
<?php

        use App\User; \\table
        use App\Email; \\table
        
        //it will return single model
        $user_id = User::select('id')->where('name','shewa')->first(); 
      
        $create = Email::create([
            'id' => $user_id,
            'last_name' => 'Otwell',
            'title' => 'Developer',
        ]);
        //finally save
        $create->save();
?>
```

Comment: how can i get the subject id from subject table and insert the id to another table on form submit

Comment: Pls see the example ,  i have created two tables. You can just use as per your table name